# how can i rewrite query string to domains in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

how can i rewrite query strings to domains in asp.net and c# ?

for example :

rewrite

```
http://www.site.com/site.aspx?SiteID=1001
```

to

```
http://www.WebSite1.com/
```

and

```
http://www.site.com/site.aspx?SiteID=1002
```

to

```
http://www.WebSite2.com/
```

---

I've seen some Blog providers do that

you create a blog , like http://example.blogspot.com and set up a domain  , Your blog address is set to www.yourdomain.com

Comment: please specify rewrite algorithm

Comment: I think he means `redirect`, but I' not sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure how to do this. But this is the idea behind it. I had worked on a similar project before

You should have a "Master" table, which contains the details of the user including which domain the user will use. The domain should be pointed to your server IP. When the user enters his domain in browser, the code should check the records which match the domain. You can also use different skins for your application.

What you are asking is more than just Url Rewriting.

Answer (score 2):

In your pageload, check for the query string and redirect to the corresponding page.
It would be something like this:

```
if(Request.QueryString["SiteId"] == "1001")
Response.Redirect("http://www.WebSite1.com/")
else if(Request.QueryString["SiteId"] == "1002")
Response.Redirect("http://www.WebSite2.com/")
```

This is if you want to redirect. Else You would need to install rewriter module in IIS and then rewrite in web.config

Comment: i want create something like blog ,
all domains come to one application